# Is there a 301 wildcard match?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

I am having great difficulty fielding all the 301 redirects that seem to be needed following a complete site redesign. Entire sub-directories and their extensive content no longer exist. If, for example, 'myolddata' was a folder that no longer exists, and was full of countless files that each no longer exists either, I would like to say "forget all that and just go to the index page". There seems no other way of closing the door on Google & Bing endlessly reporting squillions of 404's to me. Is there a way of saying in effect:

```
Redirect 301 /myolddata/  /index.html
Redirect 301 /myolddata/* /index.html
```

where the first says 'forget the folder' and the second says 'and forget everything tht was in it'?

The second part to this issue is that old PHP files and their arbitrary search parameters are logged too. Stuff like:

```
oldfile.php?this=1&that=2&somethingelse=3
oldfile.php?this=Tom&that=Dick&somethingelse=Harry
```

You get the picture. Millions of them. How can I set up a 301 to say "forget oldfile.php and any parameter with it imaginable - they are all gone!"

Your assistance, comments and advice would be incredibly valuable, so all insights welcome please!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use `mod_rewrite` rules for this using `301` status code. Use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(oldfile\.php$|myolddata(/|$)) /index.html? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` in the end will strip any existing query string.

Comment: Hi. @anubhava Can I ask you to describe that to me a little more please? I think the first part (RewriteRule ^(oldfile\.php$) is refering to files with arbitrary parameters, but is the second part ( |myolddata(/|$))  ) refering to a folder called myolddata and EVERYTHING that may be in it?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes that is absolutely correct. `|` is regex alternation here.

Comment: I can't test it today - might be after the weekend but I will get back to you!

Comment: Hi anubhava
 I tested your formula today and it works as hoped - thank you so much. I marked your answer as correct. May I tag on a small request for extra clarification too? Separating out the file name match only I derived the simplified RewriteRule ^(oldfile\.php$) /index.html? [L,NC,R=301] - this works when 'oldfile.php' is located in the root directory. How can I amend this to match all copies of oldfile.php wherever they may be found? Thank you!

Comment: You can just use: `RewriteRule (^|/)oldfile\.php$ /index.html? [L,NC,R=301]` for that usecase.

Comment: Thank you. You are truly a Regex Ninja!! Have a great day anubhava :)